# How to make a style change when a property is "true"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI, React

```
class App extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        drawerOpened: true


};
};
render () {
return(
<div>

<Drawer open={this.state.drawerOpened}>

<div style={{paddingLeft: '256px'}}> 


</div>


</div>
```

I want this padding-left only when the drawer is open (true), how do I remove the padding when closing the drawer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style={{paddingLeft: this.state.drawerOpened ? '256px' : 'initial'}}>
```

Comment: Wow, that worked, but not quite, when the page loads the div comes without padding, but when I close and open the drawer works perfectly

Comment: that's weird @Lexizz Because you set this.state.drawerOpened to true from first. console.log it inside render to see whether it's value is false or true.

Comment: I tried set to false but didn't change anything. The div always loads with initial padding, regardless of whether it is true or false. Idk what to do